# Click event added programmatically doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have an aspx page to search something in a database.
I want to put the result in a table that I programmatically generate and I want a button to download the data.

The code use to generate the button

```
TableCell download = new TableCell();
LinkButton downloadBt = new LinkButton();
downloadBt.Text = "Télécharger";
downloadBt.Click += new EventHandler(DownloadConstat);
download.Controls.Add(downloadBt);
tr.Controls.Add(download);
```

The method to execute when the user click on the button

```
protected void DownloadConstat(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("download");
}
```

The problem is that the method isn't called when clicking on the button.

Comment: you have to add the control on every postback to retain it state. so at page load add your button again and than it will work

Comment: I would recommend opening up your JavaScript console and seeing if there are any script errors on the page which causes the codebehind callback from firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add the button and assign ist event-handler before the `LoadComplete`-event of the `Page`.
An ASP.NET-page has a lifecycle that determines how and when dynamic controls can be added.

See the [ASP.NET-Page-LifeCycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

before creating dynamic controls it is good idea to go through the page life cycle. The issue you are getting is because in load event the dynamic created control is getting lost. Therefore to make those control available to have to rebuild them in page_init event so that they are available during load event.